# Undefined index when using Doctrin OneToMany association

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When debugging application I got an error in *BasicEntityPersister.php* when executing:
`$owningAssoc = $this->class->associationMappings[$assoc['mappedBy']];`
`$assoc['mappedBy']` is empty when 'sensor' expected.
I get this error when validating schema by entering *doctrine orm:validate-schema*.

> [FAIL] The entity-class EspRemoteServer\Entity\GenericSensor mapping is invalid:
>
> The association EspRemoteServer\Entity\GenericSensor#measurements refers to the owning side >field EspRemoteServer\Entity\GenericMeasurements#sensor which does not exist.

What can be wrong?
Fragments of my files:

**GenericSensor.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EspRemoteServer\Entity\Repository\GenericSensorRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sensors")
 */
class GenericSensor
{
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GenericMeasurements", mappedBy="sensor")
    **/
    protected $measurements;

    ......... 
}
```

**GenericMeasurements.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class GenericMeasurements
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GenericSensor", inversedBy="measurements")
     */
    protected $sensor;

    .....
}
```

Comment: There are a number of limitations when using [MappedSuperClass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).  Some of which are not very intuitive.  I suspect that is the problem.  Try using single table or joined table inheritance and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Single table inheritance is what I didn't want to use. It will generate one table with many nulls in unused cells.

Comment: It is solved. Only private properties is allowed in mapped superclass - https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/918

Comment: Interesting.  I guess it is an odm thing.